# Bootstrap Layout Confusion

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

I know Bootstrap is design mobile first.  I wonder if the possible layout is possible with just Bootstrap's CSS classes?

[image: layout]

Figure A on size `col-md` or larger

And when screen is `col-sm` or `col-xs`, go to B or C.  (2 different solutions).

I'm looking for the correct `div` layouts for A->B and A->C.

**The heights for each section are random because the content generated in them will be dynamic.**  I added heights in the divs just for filler, but they will be dynamic and can't be set.

The following DOES NOT work...

Fiddle ... https://jsfiddle.net/s4jj30wf/

```
<div class="row">
    <div style="background:blue" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div style="height:100px"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="background:yellow" class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div style="background:green" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div style="height:20px"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="background:pink" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div style="height:100px"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="background:red" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div style="height:100px"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background:orange" class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-4 col-xs-12">
        <div style="height:50px"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share the code you have built so far.

Comment: @NasirT  The code has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: There are 2 ways based on if the columns have static height or dynamic height. If they have static height then we have a pure css solution using the float and clear property as well as margin-top property to achieve this.

**Sample pure css with fixed height of columns:**

http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/ZBOgoe

If the height is not fixed and dynamic then we will need use of jquery to adjust the `margin-top` property in order to dynamically kill the gap between the mis-aligned 2 elements based on A->B and A->C scenario. We will be using the default jquery and modernizr js for this simple solution.

**Sample jQuery & css solution with dynamic column height:**

http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/VmjoPd

Hope this helps.

Comment: Close, but the heights are dynamic, not static.  The CSS provided is fixed.

Comment: Will it be ok to use jQuery to calculate height for you?

Comment: Depends on how involved.  I would really prefer a strictly css answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer with both the pure css and jquery solutions. If height is fixed then pure css is possible as shown but on dynamic height we will have to use jquery as we dont know how long the column will be and how it will behave. Hope the samples help.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you maybe looking for is [column ordering](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#example-column-ordering) where you can `.push-md-` and `.pull-md-`

Answer (score 0):

In document there is some flow of elements, you can't just mix them as you like unless you position them absolutely.

Using only bootstrap classes, I think the only way how to do that is to duplicate the content - you will have all A, B and C in the page and based on screen size display the one you want - using classes `visible-xs`, `hidden-sm` etc.
But duplicating content is usually not wise idea.